# Why Decision tree performed better performance versus Random Forest

Tags: python, classification

I have a network dataset including four features and 50 rows. The label represents a tag for quality of user experience from 1 to 5. I split the dataset into train test and I tried to classify them using three algorithm: SVM, Decision Tree and Random Forest. I got surprised when I saw the results. The SVM and Decision Tree exactly got the same result 1 in training and 0.95 in test. Random Forest got 0.98 in training and 0.78 in test. What's the problem?

```
QOE = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
X = QOE.iloc[:, QOE.columns != 'MOS']
y = QOE.MOS
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.7, random_state = 0)
model4 = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=0).fit(x_train, y_train)

print ('Random_Forest_train_accuracy:', model4.score(x_train, y_train))
print ('Random_Forest_test_accuracy:', model4.score(x_test, y_test))
print ('------------------------------------------------------------------')
model5 = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0).fit(x_train, y_train)
print ('Desicion_Tree_train_accuracy:', model5.score(x_train, y_train))
print ('Desicion_Tree_test_accuracy:', model5.score(x_test, y_test))
print ('------------------------------------------------------------------')
print ('SVM_train_accuracy:', model5.score(x_train, y_train))
print ('SVM_test_accuracy:', model5.score(x_test, y_test))
print ('------------------------------------------------------------------')
```

Comment: Try using RandomForestClassifier instead of RandomForestRegressor

Comment: @PatricioLoncomilla that solved my problem, by the way, SVM and decision tree have better performance in validation, they got 0.95 but random forest got 0.9. do you know why? the hyper parameters for both are default.

Comment: Maybe the random forest is overfitting, as your dataset is small